# Call an ActionMethod from one controller to another with HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I am looking at different ways to call an ActionMethod from Controller and I know that you can call an ActionMethod from One controller to another. However, we can see that some of the actionmethods are decorated with [HttpPost] and if we are calling these methods from the View then Ajax call will specify explicitly that what we are calling an action-method with [HttpPost] on it.

However, If you are calling an action method from another ActionMethods `return RedirectToAction()`. However, I am not sure where do we specify that it is [HttpPost] in this particular case?

Comment: `redirecttoacction` is for GET requests, it doesn't make sense for POST requests that can make changes in the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `RedirectToAction()`, then you're application is redirecting your browser's request to another URL.  So, if you were to look at the network activity...  Your initial POST will respond with a "302 Found" (assuming successful).  Then, a URL is provided for a redirected request to occur.  So, if you were posting to `Action1`, and `Action1` has a `RedirectToAction` to `Action2`, you would leave the `[HttpPost]` annotation on `Action1`.